# differences in LINQ queries

Tags: linq, entity-framework

Can someone explain why, when a query should be returning one string item only like in the example below;

```
From c in context.Products Where c.Id=prodId Select c.Name
```

Why cant that be done like so;

```
Dim prodDeleted as String = (From c in context.Products Where c.Id=prodId Select c.Name).ToString()
```

bvecause it returns this  (System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[System.String]) , instead of the product name

versus having to do it like so;

```
 Dim prodDeleted = (From c In ctx.products
                               Where c.Id = prodId
                               Select c).FirstOrDefault()

 Dim deletedprodname As String = prodDeleted.Name.ToString()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because all calls to Select return an IEnumerable rather than a single element.

To verify that your query really returns a single element, you need to add the call to Single. Or, if you don't care if a single element or multiple elements were returned, you can grab the first using First.

If you're not against using the VB.NET equivalent of lambda syntax, you can streamline everything:

```
Dim deletedProdName As String = 
    ctx.products.SingleOrDefault(Function(c) c.Id = prodId).Name
```

Comment: And if you can't be 100% sure it will return ANY elements, you can use [FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx), verify your result is not null, and if not, use the properties on the object.  There is no guarantee that any query run at any instance will give 0, 1, or more results, so IEnumerable is the best solution as it allows any number of results (including no values).